# Get whole text from web-page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript, and I want to know if there is a way, or ways, to get the whole text from a web-page, which means the text a person can read on a webpage (excluding any images' text).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
document.body.innerText;
```

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for ur quick reply
this is working but i m getting some squire boxes type text. how can i remove these..

Comment: share the url where you are getting square boxes.

Comment: If you are talking about the square boxes on the botom of SO. then these are html entries there.

Comment: I am using below scrip
String s = "var allLinks = document.getElementsByTagName('*'); " +
          "var str = document.body.innerText.replace(/\\s*/g, ' ');" +         //.replace(/\\s*/g, ' ');" //replace(/</?[a-zA-Z0-9]+>|<[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\s*/>|\r?\\n/g,' ')
          "alert(str);";

And at yahoo.com I m getting the [][][][][] type boxes.